# LOAD_FILE returns NULL even after using all hints

Tags: mysql

I got MySQL 5.7.15. I already disable apparmor, checked file paths( they are right and full), secure_file_priv parameter is empty, max_allowed_packet is enough, I logged as root and definitely got all grants, I also started MySQL as root and grant all rights to files. What else can be wrong?

Here is example

```
insert into `photos`(id, photo) values (50,LOAD_FILE('/home/root/files/pathDB/files/50.jpg'));
```

Here is table code

```
    drop table if exists `photos`;
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Barmar http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Comment: @Barmar where is no error message it just returns null

Comment: Did you use the full pathname of the file? Post your code.

Comment: And did you use the correct column type for the field `photo`?

Comment: That 2nd comment up there shows conditions in which `null` is returned. You are not documenting here all the facts of the case (those variables, those settings, the size) for anyone to help